# Is there a way to assign an object leveling equally the nested objects of the source?

Tags: typescript, object, automated-tests

I'm using interfaces to automate some tests, storing the required params to do some action, like the following for example:

```js
interface AdmissionFormParams {
  companyParams: {
    // some company data
  }
  employeeParams: {
    name: string
    id: number
    optionalParams?: {
      email: string
      phone: string
    }
  }
}
```

So I have a file to store all the data used along the tests (using the example for above would be like this):

**Complete registry**:

```js
const admissionDataAllParams: AdmissionFormParams = {
  companyParams: {
    // some company data
  },
  employeeParams: {
    name: 'Manolo',
    id: 5432,
    optionalParams: {
      email: 'Manolo@gmail.com',
      phone: '99999999'
    }
  }
}
```

**Incomplete Registry**:

```js
const admissionDataRequiredParams: AdmissionFormParams = {
  companyParams: {
    // some company data
  },
  employeeParams: {
    name: 'John',
    id: 2425
  }
}
```

This two are being used to complete the Create scenario.

After the register successfully succeed, the Employee's data will be visible at one tab of the registry, while the Company's data in another.

I have to assert both of them, and for this im using a new interface ommiting the `optionalParams` and making them all required, cause the assertion will be done in both cases (empty or filled fields):

```js
interface EmployeeDataParams {
  name: string
  id: number
  email: string
  phone: string
}
```

How can I create an object assigning the data of `admissionData.employeeParams` but using it's `optionalParams` on the same level to all of them (all required)?

I was using as the follow, but the file is getting tooo extensive (used some small examples here).

**Incomplete registry**:

```js
const employeeDataRequiredParams: EmployeeDataParams = {
  name: admissionDataRequiredParams.employeeParams.name,
  id: admissionDataRequiredParams.employeeParams.id,
  email: '',
  phone: ''
}
```

**Complete registry**:

```js
const employeeDataAllParams: EmployeeDataParams = {
  name: admissionDataAllParams.employeeParams.name,
  id: admissionDataAllParams.employeeParams.id,
    email: admissionDataAllParams.employeeParams.optionalParams?.email ?? "",
    phone: admissionDataAllParams.employeeParams.optionalParams?.phone ?? ""
}
```

Comment: Your example `employeeData` intializer has errors in it, because `optionalParams` might not exist.  Could you fix that so this is a [mre]?  Once you do fix that, does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WJ7Lrw) meet your needs?  If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Oh, ok, i forgot i am using two objects for each case (complete / incomplete register), hope its not confusing now.

Comment: @jcalz Yeah, this works perfectly better, just a question, the `optionalParams` object will  also be acessible? once i have them all deconstructed can I Omit it at the first desconstruction you suggested?

Comment: [You didn't fix the errors](https://tsplay.dev/mAdl1N); could you please [edit] to do that, perhaps [like this](https://tsplay.dev/mp8XMm)?  Then we can answer the question with something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mbK72W)

Comment: Right, sorry, strangerly the compiler wasnt throwing me this errors.
LGTM, waiting for you answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your example code, I think the least repetitive approach would be to use [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to copy the `employeeParams` object into two variables, and then [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals) those variables back into a new object literal.  For example:

```
function toDataParams(x: AdmissionFormParams): EmployeeDataParams {
    const { optionalParams = { email: "", phone: "" }, ...employeeParams } =
        x.employeeParams;
    return { ...optionalParams, ...employeeParams };
}
```

In the first line, we destructure `x.employeeParams` into a `optionalParams` variable (which, if absent in `x.employeeParams`, becomes a [default](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#default_value) value `{email: "", phone: ""}`) and then put the [rest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#rest_property) of the properties into an `employeeParams` variable.

So `optionalParams` is therefore of type `{email: string; phone: string}`, and `employeeParams` is of type `{name: string; id: number}` (and does *not* contain an `optionalParams` property).  Then we just spread those together into the return value, which is necessarily of type `EmployeeDataParams`.

---

It's possible that depending on your actual use case there are other approaches which turn out to use less code, but given the example as written this is fairly minimal.  If you don't care about the returned value possibly having an unused `optionalParams` property, you can get even terser this way:

```
function toDataParams(x: AdmissionFormParams): EmployeeDataParams {
    return {
        ...x.employeeParams.optionalParams ?? { email: "", phone: "" },
        ...x.employeeParams
    };
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIBMC2wDOPgD2IAYgVJgApxRyY7IDeAsAFDLvIIGYAOcIATyo06ALkasOU5AHoZyHNxRde-AcnRwwcSRwC+u9hF4AbAgIgRhtHOOZtp7ELQjicYKKADmh6cHTiIACumABG0L5SBDxghM4m1nQA-HaRjsjGcMAmbh7eaY48ABZErgp5ID4OjgbVyLW1rKxcIO7IcFi4+EQAIlpwqCYJ1DbiGNh4caTkifQAvBJ1KnyCs6l1UnIKSpzcK+qa2r56ADS+xjxmFlYjYovpyM6YZQDkALL8BGYvZxsc-uIAKwAFgAzAAmX4PaKxIhwYYiWz3B4cTLZcTvT5mAACXkwWRMADoVD8CtJiqUMQBOGm0mkvMm1KQNJosZpENodCbdEB9bQAJQgAEcgsAoBB0Gs0J1JkRppRbvNkexlmopfYHltFM9dqpBBp+scoajTOZLOqyU9XgApAhFECkv7sAHIcHA8GA46sRpsligSCwRAoACipuufLgs2VjxcuU8lV8LuCYQidTROXK8aqUgpIDK7iz3tZMCCIAQsJAyDABAjswAFAAPMYynny2YASnEocuZogtcV0ZabQYyBhcXhUYWI-T4gARLOTshc2V5-VF4SNxcruaB3pkHMyQ3CVve7MANy+LZDsCjmLjhGjRgZfHozPeM9Lkp5uPvpkcK8cjeJ7XOqMbPD+lQfkmIThFAH4+lI4pgEEUCViOG6EmOcIPnQ66bmGO6IvUF4sD6xaluWcRVjW-SzOCjbNtyUxkAqiKdsg3bbn2tEDhqHBIShaFkhhR7AYRNiYXe2FRkkSRPjOyDzouy5zrOa7CRuokETciLHCRtRAA)

Comment: Thanks a lot, i'll be going to use the first approach.